# BOOST_FOREACH over a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, boost

I want to use the `BOOST_FOREACH` macro to iterate over a bunch of values in a `vector` of mine. The vector looks like this:

```
struct _Element
{
    int key;
    // more variables here
}

elements = new std::vector<_Element *>;
```

I'm very new to C++, and I'm a bit stumped as to how I would actually iterate over the contained `_Element *`'s. Why doesn't this work?

```
BOOST_FOREACH(_Element *currentElem, rootElement->_document->elements)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Compiling this gives me an error:

```
shared.cc:146:37: error: no viable conversion from 'std::__1::vector<_Element *, std::__1::allocator<_Element *> >' to '_Element *'
    BOOST_FOREACH(_Element *currentElem, rootElement->_document->elements)
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: hm, don't do `new std::vector<_Element *>`, but simply `auto elements = std::vector<Element>` instead, do use c++11 if you don't have a reason to do otherwise, the you won't need `BOOST_FOREACH`, even if there is a possibility of fixing your code

Comment: Are you using some XML library here or attempting to write one yourself?

Comment: `_Element` is a name reserved for the implementation, don't use it. (Any _A - _Z prefix is reserved)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `elements` is `vector<_Element *>*`, so you need to dereference it before passing it to `BOOST_FOREACH`.

```
BOOST_FOREACH(_Element *currentElem, *(rootElement->_document->elements))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

That will fix the compilation error, but since you're new to C++, there's a very good chance you don't need all those pointers you've declared. For instance, your code should probably look like this:

```
struct Element            // do not use leading underscore followed by 
                          // uppercase letter, that's reserved
{
    int key;
    // more variables here
};

std::vector<Element> elements = std::vector<Element>;
// vector of Element, not Element*. And elements is a vector, not vector *
```

Finally, if you have a compiler that supports C++11's range based `for` you don't need `BOOST_FOREACH`.

```
for(auto&& currentElem : rootElement.document.elements)
// notice that I've gotten rid of all the pointers within rootElement
{
  // currentElem is a reference to the current element in the elements vector
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
elements = new std::vector<_Element *>;
```

indicates that `elements` is of pointer type.

*Technically* that means that you need to dereference it, `*elements`, for use with `BOOST_FOREACH`.

But that's still wholly wrong on the level of good programming practice.

Instead:

- Let `elements` just be a `vector`, directly. Not a pointer.
- Don't use `new`.
- Use a C++11 **range-based `for`** if your compiler supports it. If not, then upgrade your compiler and use a C++11 range-based `for`.

It can look like this:

```
for( auto const& item : elements )
{
    // Do whatever
}
```

or if the items are of small/simple enough type that a bit of value copying doesn't matter, just

```
for( auto const item : elements )
{
    // Do whatever
}
```

---

In passing: in addition to avoiding needless huge library dependencies, and avoiding use of raw pointers where practical, you might want to reconsider using a prefix underscore as a member name convention. Prefix underscores are used by a lot of other software and are reserved in the global namespace. A nice alternative is a suffix underscore.

Answer (score 0):

`BOOST_FOREACH` expects a container not a pointer to a container as the second argument.

Use

```
BOOST_FOREACH(_Element *currentElem, *(rootElement->_document->elements))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do :

```
BOOST_FOREACH(_Element *currentElem, *(rootElement->_document->elements))
{
   .....
}
```

Or if your compiler supports C++11, prefer using the built-in range iteration:

```
for(auto element : *(rootElement->_document->elements))
{
   ....
}
```

Comment: hehe, Ill delete mine its redundant